# Resharper going crazy on VB.NET indentation

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, resharper, indentation

I cannot for the life of me figure out why ReSharper 8.2.1 is doing this on a full code cleanup to my class.

**Before:**

```
''' <summary>
''' Data contract to store details of a generic service fault
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class ServiceFaultDetails

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Reason why this fault was raised.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <DataMember()> _
    Private mReason As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Overloaded constructor to initialise the reason and original exception message properties.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="reason">Reason why the fault was raised.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(ByVal reason As String)
        mReason = reason
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Accessor for the reason field.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ReadOnly Property Reason() As String
        Get
            Return mReason
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

**After:**

```
Public Class ServiceFaultDetails
''' <summary>
''' Reason why this fault was raised.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
                                <DataMember()>
    Private mReason As String

                                ''' <summary>
                                ''' Overloaded constructor to initialise the reason and original exception message properties.
                                ''' </summary>
                                ''' <param name="reason">Reason why the fault was raised.</param>
                                ''' <remarks></remarks>
                                Public Sub New(ByVal reason As String)
        mReason = reason
    End Sub

                                ''' <summary>
                                ''' Accessor for the reason field.
                                ''' </summary>
                                ''' <value></value>
                                ''' <returns></returns>
                                ''' <remarks></remarks>
                                Public ReadOnly Property Reason() As String
        Get
            Return mReason
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The bit that's sending the reformatting haywire is the XML doc block on the first class field, **mReason.**  Removing this document block makes the reformatting work much more sensibly (although it removes the extra line after the Class line, and before the field declaration.

I've been having a poke around at the various indentation and formatting options in Resharper and VS2010, and I'm utterly lost.  Anyone have a clue why that XML doc block is breaking the reformatting so badly?

Comment: ReSharper doesn't work well (in my experience) with VB.NET. I tried it and had to uninstall it because it made a hash of everything. If you are using Visual Studio you shouldn't need a tool to indent your code for you as this is done automatically.

Comment: I'm rapidly approaching that conclusion myself.  It isn't so much to aid with my own code as it would have been a useful tool for refactoring some very old, gnarly code that doesn't even get the basics of formatting correct - doing all of the formatting copperplate by hand is tiresome, and there are many limits to VS's own indentation support.  I may keep Resharper if the other refactor tools prove beneficial but this is a big strike against as I can't even figure out what to disable in the indentation options to allow the use of the rest of the function.  I may send this to their support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in ReSharper 8.2.1-3: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-423225

Hopefully it will get fixed in ReSharper 9.

Putting single ' in new line right after indenting linebreak (Public Class ServiceFaultDetails from your example), while not very elegant, does the trick for me.